# Trouble with ERROR 1146 in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

So I'm doing a basic MySQL tutorial using Python and I first used the following code to create a simple database.

```
import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'test623', 'testdb')

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Writers")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Writers (Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, Name VARCHAR(25))")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES ('Jack London')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES ('Honore de Balzac')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES ('Lion Feuchtwanger')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES ('Emile Zola')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES ('Truman Capote')")
```

That executes fine.  Then I run the following MySQL commands.

```
USE Writers;
SELECT * FROM Writers;
```

That last line throws the error

> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'Writers.Writers' doesn't exist

Anyone know what causes this or why it's trying to access something called `Writers.Writers` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connect to MySQL and set your default DB to be `testdb`. So that's where the Writers table is created. You then switch over to `Writers`, where there is no such table. e.g.

```
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'test623', 'testdb')
                                                       ^^^^^^^--- default DB
```

Doing

```
SELECT * FROM testdb.Writers
```

would work, as would

```
use testdb;
SELECT * FROM Writers
```

Comment: Thanks, totally got database and table mixed up